# Running Ruby gem exe file from outside the gem

Tags: rubygems

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to run an executable I'm building for a gem.  I've been able to make some progress, but it feels like I'm doing it wrong.  I have the following structure.

```
my_gem
|__ exe
  |__ foo
|__ lib
  |__ commands
     |__ foo 
        |__ actions.rb
```

My `exe/foo` file has the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'commands/foo/actions'

MyGem::Commands::Foo.start(ARGV)
```

While inside the `my_gem` directory, if I execute `bundle exec exe/foo`, everything seems to work fine. This particular command actually generates a Rails app inside `my_gem/the_app`.  This works, but I've noticed some subtle problems with my command and the newly generated Rails app.  What I'd really like to do is run the command from outside of the gem directory. If I execute `my_gem/exe/foo`, I get the following error though:

```
/home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- commands/foo/actions (LoadError).
```

I get the same error if just execute `exe/foo` from inside the `my_gem` folder as well.

I've been able to get around this by running `rake build` and `rake install`.  Then I can run `foo` just about wherever I want and it picks up the installed version from outside the gem.  However, it's a pain to build/install the gem every time I want to test it out.

Is there a way I can execute the development version of the command from outside the gem directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to exe/foo and it seemed to help

`lib = File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)`